# Как перемещать объект только при клике по нему?

Tags: swift

Чувствую, что я уже близок к цели! ) Объект реагирует только по клику на себя, но и перемещается только по своей границе.... Как исправить?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

//создаем свойство
var figureUser = SKSpriteNode!()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    //инициализируем свойство
    figureUser = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circle")

    //определяем позицию square на экране
    figureUser.position = CGPoint(x: 25, y: 25)

    //даем имя
    figureUser.name = "circle"

    figureUser.userInteractionEnabled = false

    //добавляем square на экран
    addChild(figureUser)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

    if (node.name == "circle") {

        let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(touchLocation, duration: 0)

        figureUser.runAction(moveAction)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: надо в `touchesBegan` проверять что нажатие было где вам надо, и если нет, то в `touchesMoved` ничего не делать

Comment: Тоже думаю в этом направлении, но не могу понять как грамотно написать условие с привязкой к объекту...

Answer (score 1):

Сам спросил и сам ответил. ) Вместо `touchesBegan` нужно использовать `touchesMoved`.

Comment: у вас и есть touchesMoved

Comment: Да, в первой версии кода есть. Во второй случайно изменил и потом долго думал почему неправильно все работает )